# How to pass shell variable in docker build?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Is there a way to pass shell variables to "docker build", so it may be used inside the Dockerfile being built?

The best I could come up with was setting the shell variables and again passing them as build-arg/ARG:

`docker build . -t abc:1.1 --build-arg SOMEARG=$SHELLVARIABLET`

Is there a better way?

Comment: No, that's the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It's good if the shell variables are not sensitive (eg : no credentials) and will remain the same when the container is created (Because docker build creates an immutable image).

Otherwise a better practice is  to pass an env file when using a the docker run command (that create an instance of the container based on the image)

```
docker run  --env-file .env
```

[Docker run Doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)